# What happened to Blinky?

Tags: plot-explanation, trollhunters

*Trollhunters* starts with Blinky reading a book and summarizing the series leading up to the movie, but at the end of the movie the main character turns back time to when before he became trollhunter, and Toby instead finds the amulet. And that's the end of the movie, implying that all of the other characters, including Blinky, didn't remember anything that happened, since their entire timeline was reset. So how could Blinky be telling the story the whole time?

Is there a post-credit scene I missed?

Or maybe when Blinky was reading the story, when he got to the finale the pages were stuck together, and what it really said is that Toby got resurrected by magical powers, then they all grew up together happily into college etc., starting a new franchise

Then one day they might have been talking about what nightmares could have been, when they discuss time being turned back etc., but then they all immediately dismiss it as an imagination, maybe Blinky's pages skipped to that part?